# Display a certain value in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I cant get this function to work, I need the array to show a certain value in the var, but it wont work. I struggle with this function:

```
var tall = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
if(nummer == 11) {
    var sjkk = document.getElementById("sjkk").value;
    if (sjkk.indexOf(tall)) {
        document.getElementById("tall").innerHTML = "Yes, the number exist in the array";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("tall").innerHTML = "No, the number does not exist in the array";
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `tall.indexOf(sjkk)` instead of `sjkk.indexOf(tall)`?

Comment: Try this..if(tall.indexOf(sjkk) > -1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve the required results with below code,

```
var tall = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
let uniqueTall = {};tall.forEach((value)=>{uniqueTall[value]=1})
if(nummer == 11) {
    var sjkk = document.getElementById("sjkk").value;   
    document.getElementById("tall").innerHTML = uniqueTall[sjkk] ? "Yes, the number exist in the array": "No, the number does not exist in the array";    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for value in array, hence, `indexOf` has to be other way around.

Also, `.value` will return a string, hence, to correctly check the existence, you will need to convert it into a **number** first as all the values in `array` are `numbers`.

Hence, you will need to update from

```
sjkk.indexOf(tall)
```

to

```
tall.indexOf(Number(sjkk)) !== -1
```

or

```
tall.includes(Number(sjkk))
```

Comment: You're playing a bit too fast here ;) Note that "sjkk" is a value of an input, and hence a string.

Comment: @georg - Ah! My bad. I simply overlooked that part. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf method should be applied to an array like this :

```
if (tall.indexOf(parseInt(sjkk, 10)) > -1) {
        document.getElementById("tall").innerHTML = "Ja, tallet er i arrayen";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("tall").innerHTML = "Nei, tallet er ikke i arrayen";
    }
```

Comment: With `parseInt` it's usually a good idea to [include the radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Description): `parseInt(sjkk, 10)`, for example.

Comment: Here if will fail if the index is 0. if (tall.indexOf(parseInt(sjkk)) > -1) or if (tall.indexOf(parseInt(sjkk)) != -1) will be good

Comment: Thanks to both of you!